# decrease the stock when the transaction is completed codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i want to decrease stock product when transactions is complete, I try with foreach from data but the stock is not decreased correctly

CONTROLLER :

```
for ($i=0; $i < $count ; $i++) { 

//SAVE DETAIL PENJUALAN
$data[] = array(
    'nonota'     => $this->input->post('nonota',TRUE),
    'id_brg'     => $this->input->post('kd_brg',TRUE)[$i],
    'nama_brg'   => $this->input->post('nama',TRUE)[$i],
    'jml_brg'    => $this->input->post('jml',TRUE)[$i],
    'harga_brg'  => $this->input->post('harga',TRUE)[$i], 
);

//DELETE CART
$cart[] = array(
    'rowid' => $this->input->post('rowid',TRUE)[$i],
    'qty'   => 0 
);

$update[] = array(
'id'    => $this->input->post('kd_brg',TRUE)[$i],
'stok'  => 'stok' -  $this->input->post('jml',TRUE)[$i]
);


$this->M_penjualan->updatestock($update,'tbl_barang');

}
```

MODEL

```
function updatestock($update) {
        $this->db->update_batch('tbl_barang',$update,'id');
    }
```

Comment: Where is the code of decreasing the stock?

Comment: function updatestock($update) {
        $this->db->update_batch('tbl_barang',$update,'id');
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Maybe products ids are not the same as the ones you get from the iteration.

2.Take a look at this line:

```
'stok'  => 'stok' -  $this->input->post('jml',TRUE)[$i]
```

You change value of a string, because 'stok' is a string. It would be something else if you would make `$stok - $this->input...` .Of course if stock represents some number.

3.Also I would first try to update with simple update. `$this->db->set('stok', 'stok-'.$stok, false);` - somewhere in your model function.